# Clear an interval after a certain time limit in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I'm trying to stop this JavaScript function after 5 seconds.

Here is the code :

```
<p id="para"></p>

var niceThings = ["You're cool", "You're smart", "You're good looking", "You're a baus", "You're a cool cat."];
var i =0;

function compliment () {

    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = niceThings[i];

    if(i < niceThings.length-1) {
        i++;    
    }
    else {
        i=0;    
    }
}

window.onload = setInterval(compliment, 500);
```

I'm sure there's a way to use the setTimeout method somewhere, but I'm a newb. Any thoughts?

Comment: What seems to be the problem here and what is your requirement ?

Comment: I want this function to stop after a certain time period, say 5 seconds or so.

Comment: As of now it will cycle indefinitely through these compliments every half second

Comment: so call clearTimeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setInterval` returns a token which can be passed to `clearInterval` after 5 seconds to stop the silly function in its tracks.

Also, note that you can simplify your array-looping logic using the modulo (`%`) operator.

```js
var niceThings = [
  "You're cool",
  "You're smart",
  "You're good looking",
  "You're a baus",
  "You're a cool cat."
]

var p = document.getElementById("para")
var i = 0

function compliment () {
  p.textContent = niceThings[i]
  i = (i + 1) % niceThings.length
}

setTimeout(clearInterval, 5000,
  setInterval(compliment, 500)
)
```

```html
<p id="para"></p>
```

Comment: Sorry on the delay gyre. I am still learning stackedoverflow and coding in general. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem, and you're welcome :) Good luck with the rest of your project.